# Lebesgue's integrability condition in several variables

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

The well known [Lebesgue's condition of Riemann integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) says that a bounded function in one variable
$f\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere.

I vaguely remember that the same should be true for functions in several variables, say for functions defined on a cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is that correct? A reference will be very helpful.

Comment: A reference for the fact that you mentioned is V.A. Zorich's book Mathematical Analysis, vol.II, page 110-113, Sec.11.1. As it happens, I am now using this book in the undergraduate analysis class I am teaching this year.

Comment: Many thanks! This answers the question completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fact is found in T. Apostol, *Mathematical Analysis*, section 10-5.

The proof is straightforward: if the set of points of discontinuity has positive measure, then the upper and lower sums are far apart.  I wanted to include a reference for this in something I was writing (*Classics on Fractals*), but had to ask a lot of people before I found a proof in a textbook.

Comment: Thank you! Section 10-5 contains a proof in the case of one variable, while section 14-4 contains the statement of the criterion for several variables and just states that the proof is similar. This is sufficient for me for the moment.